# Format pasted rows within userforum-textbox into concatenation or borderline?

Tags: vba, border, userform

I get a mismatch error in this line :

```
row_str = Join(cell_rng, Chr(10))
```

Thank you. I am intermediate.

I attached a piece of the code below:

`````
    Dim last_row As String
    Dim last_col As String
    Dim office_str As String
    Dim lookupVal As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim seperate_cells, cell_rng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim row_str As String        


With Contacts
    For i = 2 To last_row
        Set cell_rng = Rows(i & ":" & i + 1)
        For Each r In cell_rng.Rows
           seperate_cells = cellsSeparator(r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
           If row_str = "" Then
            row_str = Join(cell_rng, Chr(10))
           Else
            row_str = row_str & vbLf & Join(cell_rng, Chr(10))
           End If
        Next
        Debug.Print row_str
        Client_Finder.result.Text = Client_Finder.result.Text & vbLf & row_str
    Next i       
End With
````
`````

Comment: So, do you want pasting **a row** in a text box? Can you explain what you mean saying that? Should we understand that `Client_Finder.result` is a text box ("result") on "Client_Finder" form? If not, can you explain what it is? Can you post a picture with the row in discussion and another one with the desired text of that text box?

Comment: Please, also explain what "concatenation or borderline" should mean, in the question context.

Comment: Hi.   @FaneDuru Correct Client_Finder is my user forum and the result is my text box. So I compared the selected value from the combo box with the desired range in the spreadsheet and if it matches then paste the entire row into the result(textbox). Code is working the only problem the data doesn't have a border to separate the cells. I. can't share picture because it's confidential data.  I want the row to either formated as border to separate the data or to to have the data wrapped in one line as shown above

Comment: Let us take it step by step. So, if you need the data on a single line, you should set the text box 'MultiLine` property to false. Now, I do not understand what do you mean by saying "the row to either formatted as border"... I can help you to separate each word by, let us say, " | " characters. But this cannot be done on the entire row, because there will be a lot of such separators for all the cells, even empty. If this looks convenient can you define the row to be copied in terms of involved column? I mean to restrict the entire row of only `Range("A" & i & ":" & "E" & i)`, as in example?

Comment: So I set it as Multi-Line because it can be the same office code but different trade types so when I select office code it will copy 1-4 rows of data associated with that office code. But when it copy the rows from the data in the spreadsheet to the text box instead of the border as a separator it's spaced as separator so the data looks chunky so I am trying to replace the space separator with something like Char 10

Comment: I am afraid I still cannot get you. Do you say that the above code copies more then one row  in the text box? For "different trade types"... Is the text box in discussion  large enough to let all the copied row text on a single line? The copying code cannot add a separator! This can be add using another way of copying (without involving clipboard), but not understanding what you need, I am afraid I cannot help.

Comment: Please, try the code I posted and send some feedback

Comment: Hi Fani, sorry if I am not clear so as you said the above code copies more than one row in the text box? For "different trade types".  and what is the other copying method. Thank you

Comment: I am afraid, again I cannot understand what you mean... Do you ask me how to proceed in case of more rows should be copied, at once? If yes, you must show us your code. Only in such a situation I will be able to provide something to replace it and do what you say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the next way. It will place the values of the necessary specific row in the text box, each value separated by " | ":

```
Sub testSeparatorsBetweenRowCells()
 'your existing code...
 Dim arr, rngR As Range
  For i = 2 To last_row
            lookupVal = cells(i, office_str)
            ' Compare ComboBox with the range from the spreadsheet
            If lookupVal = Office_Code Then
                Set rngR = rows(i & ":" & i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'Set a range which will return all cells value in the row, except the empty ones
                arr = arrCells(rngR)  'call a function able to make an array from the range set in the above line
                Client_Finder.result.Text = Client_Finder.result.Text & vbLf & Join(arr, " | ") 'add the text obtained by joining the array to the next line of existing text
            End If
    Next i
End Sub

Function arrCells(rng As Range) As Variant
   Dim arr, Ar As Range, i As Long, C As Range
   ReDim arr(rng.cells.count - 1) 'ReDim the array to be filled as the range cells number.
                                           '- 1, because the array is 0 based...
   For Each Ar In rng.Areas       'iterate between the range areas
        For Each C In Ar.cells      'iterate between cells of each area
            arr(i) = C.value: i = i + 1 'put each cell value in the array
        Next
   Next
   arrCells = arr                      'make the function returning the arr
End Function
```

If the text in the text box still goes on the next line, try making the text box property `WordWrap` `False`. If you cannot see all the text, make the textbox wider or decrease its font size.

Please, test it and send some feedback.

**Edited**:
Please, try understanding the next piece of code, able to deal with copying more rows at once:

```
Sub testCopyingMoreRows()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long, rng As Range, r As Range, arr, strRow As String
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   i = 9
   Set rng = sh.rows(i & ":" & i + 1)
   'you ca select cells, rows (even not consecutive) and use:
   'Set rng = Selection.EntireRow 'just uncomment this code line...
   'extract rows and paste their contents (exept the empty cells) in Imediate Window
   For Each r In rng.rows
        arr = arrCells(r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
        If strRow = "" Then
            strRow = Join(arr, " | ")
        Else
            strRow = strRow & vbLf & Join(arr, " | ")
        End If
   Next
   Debug.Print strRow
   'instead returning in Imediate Window, you can do it in your text box (uncomment the next line):
   'Client_Finder.result.Text = Client_Finder.result.Text & vbLf & strRow
End Sub
```

The code uses the same function `arrCells`...

Comment: Can you add comments to know the difference? Thank you for your patience and help

Comment: It gave me compile error : Function or Sub not defined

Comment: @Jake8281 Didn't you copy the `arrCells` function, too? When say something about this type of error, **you should say on which code line the error appears**. I will comment the code, in a way to make it easy to be understood, if having some VBA knowledge. Yesterday I had to close my laptop. It was very late in my country...

Comment: @Jake8281 I commented the above code, in a way to make it understood even if the VBA level is not so high... If something (still) not clear, do not hesitate to ask for clarification.

Comment: Hi bro, Thank you for your help.  one more thing needed so I replaced "   l   " with Chr(10) after every cell as a separator it works perfectly. The only thing left is to add new space between rows if I have more than one row pasted in the text box do you know how to do that and also. I want to know why you used arr and rngR as a range. Thank you

Comment: @Jake828 I think, when you need help, it is good to also answer the clarification questions. **I clearly asked you to show us the code copying more then a row**. I will try writing a new piece of code, or I will adapt the existing one, according to the way you do that. Now, **you cannot directly extract an array from a discontinuous range**! It will contain only the first `Area` values. That's why the code previously creates the discontinuous range and process it in a separate function to create an array. What "a space between rows are you referring? In construction I provided, `vbLf` does it.

Comment: @Jake828 How your code proceeds, in case of "different trade types"? Do you have such a code? If not, try describing in words what do you have in mind? Should you select and copy more consecutive rows and want pasting them in the text box?

Comment: @Jake828 I need to go out for a while. Since you do not show your code copying more rows, I will post a generic code showing how to deal such a situation.

Comment: The code up there before you adjusted was the -->main code for copying rows. 
Your code works perfectly. as it separates the line after each cell. So I want to do is to separate between rows. Answering your question there is no code for trade types. I am just pasting rows that match office code selection. I attached the redacted picture up there. so after 303 phone numbers, that's the start of the new row, and am trying to add another empty line to separate these 2 rows. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Then, did you see/try/understand the second code I pasted? It should do exactly what you want. If you manually intend to select rows, you can replace `Set rng = sh.rows(i & ":" & i + 1)` with `Set rng = Selection`. Or select cells (even discontinuously) in a column and use `Set rng = Selection.EntireRow`. In fact,  `Set rng = Selection.EntireRow` works in moth cases (selecting cells or rows)... I edited my last code and inserted this code line, too.

Comment: I combined your upper 2 codes together and it's giving me compile error: For each may only iterate over collection or an array. Let me update the code above.

Comment: Please check the updated code I am using now

Comment: @Jake828  I am afraid that you did not understand too much from the two codes. You did not combine anything.  First code works well to process **a single row**. The second one should work to process more rows at once. Where in your code more rows are involved? Then you ruined what I tried showing. Who told that you can skip the function able to transform a discontinuous range in an array. Only an array can be joined. I cannot say anything about your pseudo code, sorry... You only proved that did not understand too much from my codes... I really do not know how I can help you, in this situation

Comment: I am so sorry about that. There was a miscommunication on my end. Let me re-read the second code and let you know if I need any help. Thank you for your patience and time

Comment: @Jake828 If you are able to tell me (in words) in which circumstances (those "different trade types") you need to process more rows **at once**, I can try creating a piece of code for you. If not, I am afraid that I do not know how I can help you.

Comment: @Jake828 Do not **re-read** it. Try it! Only after that you can try understanding it, I think...

Comment: I used your code. I got mis match error in that line I mentioned above. Thank you so much for your help. My deadline is tomorrow

Comment: @Jake828 Did you test the code **as it is**? If yes, which line can raise such an error? If not, why you modify it? If modified, how could I know what wrong happens in your 'updated' code? It is late in my country and in some minutes I will close my laptop. Please, try the code as it is, without any modification and confirm that it works or not. Then, if you try adapting it, without understanding what the code does, I have some imagination but I cannot imagine what you wrongly modified, sorry...

Comment: @Jake828 I think you should use the first code for the second part of the job, too. Since you do not know how to select more rows, why should it not work on each row respecting the necessary condition? I am closing my laptop. If you have some other ideas will try helping you tomorrow, supposing that it is not too late.

Comment: The first code combined with the modification code I  just wrote solved the issue. Thank you so much, brother